# Not able to start Elasticsearch, no matter what I do

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch

Running Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle VM.

Deployed two Ubuntu instances on AWS.

I will list out all the steps I did. Please let me know where I have gone wrong.

1. Copied the pem file to home directory    `cp ~/Downloads/TetraSearchDemo.pem`
2. Changed the permissions of the pem file to `-r-------- 1`
3. Connected to Ubuntu instance `ssh -i ".pem file" <public dns of the instance>`
4. Installed Java `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless`
5. Checked the presence of Java

`openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)`

I think this is where something is going wrong. In the training video I am following, the trainer is getting `java version "1.7.0_111"` along with the above versions but I am not. Please advise if it is ok.

Moving on

6. Downloaded Debian version of elasticsearch

`wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.8.0-amd64.deb`

7. Added the package `sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-7.8.0-amd64.deb`
8. Added some default values `sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10`
   Here the trainer got an output saying `Adding system startup for` but I did not get any output.
9. Finally, tried to start elasticsearch `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`

but continuosly getting this error

```
....] Starting elasticsearch (via systemctl): elasticsearch.serviceJob for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

I have followed the tips offered in other threads like editing the nano text file and so on, but nothing worked. Please help me

Edit: I entered the yml file and did the following changes:

Deleted `discovery.seed_hosts: ["instance1 private IP", "instance2 private IP"]`

and added the following

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["instance1 private IP", "instance2 private IP"]
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

After making the above changes, to check if they have taken effect `curl -XGET "instance1 private IP:9200"`, getting the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ip> port 9200: Connection refused
```

Comment: Just a guess: try to install the java jdk instead of jre. openjdk-11-jdk-headless should be ok.

Comment: @atmin I did it now `sudo apt install default-jdk.`, but the java version is still not appearing and elasticsearch is still failing to start

Comment: Hm. You could try to start elasticsearch from scratch to see the StackTrace. 
    "locate  elasticsearch/bin"
Then go there and "sudo ./elasticsearch". Good luck!

Comment: @atmin...thank you. I tried the locate, but it did not give any output. Tried everything